# Errror in SearchKeywordUpdate on uploading new products by API

Tags: php, api, product

Since beginning of July we get an error on uploading new products by API function.

The error message is:

```
Argument 1 passed to Shopware\Core\Content\Product\DataAbstractionLayer\SearchKeywordUpdater::Shopware\Core\Content\Product\DataAbstractionLayer\{closure}() must be an instance of Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Field\Field, null given
```

By the error log I found out that the error is raised on line 244 in module `core/Content/Product/DataAbstractionLayer/SearchkeywordUpdater.php`:

```
$fields = array_filter($fields, function (Field $field) { ... }
```

It seems, that some change in 6.4.0.2 results in this error message because the variable `$field` does not contain an object "Field" but NULL. But I don't now why and how to fix it.

At this time I inserted a line `continue;` in the parent for each loop, now ignoring any search keywords.

Has anyone here an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you must update Shopware. This issue: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-16301 is closed and resolved.